# Moving contacts between groups in iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I move a contact from the All group to another group in an iOS device?
I don't see a way to do this on my iPhone XR with iOS 14.4.1

Comment: btw, you really should be on 14.4.2 because of the security issue. Don't wait.